# SUM multiple values after a substring within all cells in a column in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, re2

For an open source chat analyser in Google Sheets, I need to extract all numeric values after a substring (`Example`), then total them.

For example, if a cell contains `Example1 another text 123 Example500 text`, `Example1` and `Example500` should be extracted out, and their numeric values summed to `501`.

This is complicated further by needing to obtain the total for a column of messages.

---

What I've tried already:

- `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "Example(\d+)")`: This only extracts the first matching value, but works!
- `=SUM(SPLIT(A1, "Example"))`: This works for messages that only include my target string, but falls apart when other strings are included. The output could possibly be filtered to results that start with a number, but this is very messy and possibly a red herring.
- `CONCATENATE`ing all my cells together, then searching for numbers. This is error-prone due to additional numbers within messages.

Comment: How about the extract thing with [`Example(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/FQx4Do/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble Only gets the first one unfortunately. The regex I used is hacky and messy, yours is better, but it's trying to pull multiple out that is challenging. Looks like `REGEXEXTRACT` for multiple values if you have multiple matching groups.

Comment: Also try `=IF(ISTEXT(A1);SUM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1;"Example(\d+)|.";"$1 ");" "));0)`

Comment: @bobblebubble Consider adding a answer.  `BYROW` could be useful for arraying the solution.

Comment: @TheMaster I wonder how to work this `BYROW` in, I'm new to Google Sheets, maybe you want to edit my answer if you like :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=LAMBDA(x, REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(\w+)\d+")&
 SUMPRODUCT(IF(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(x, "\w+\d+")), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(x, "\w+(\d+)"), )))(SPLIT(A1, " "))
```

[image]

### update 1:

```
=LAMBDA(x, REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(\D+)\d+")&
 SUMPRODUCT(IF(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(x, "\D+\d+")), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(x, "\D+(\d+)"), )))(SPLIT(A1, " "))
```

[image]

---

### update 2:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(xx, REGEXEXTRACT(xx, "(\D+)\d+")&
 BYROW(LAMBDA(x, IF(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(x, "\D+\d+")), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(x, "\D+(\d+)"), ))(SPLIT(xx, " ")), LAMBDA(x, SUMPRODUCT(x))))
 (A1:INDEX(A:A, MAX((A:A<>"")*ROW(A:A)))))
```

if you start from A2 just change `A1:` to `A2:`

[image]

Comment: Damn, this was close, but only works for single digit numbers (e.g. changing first to `Example99` results in `Example911`. That's my mistake for not stating multi-digit requirement, updating post now.

Comment: @JakeLee answer updated

Comment: That works perfectly on a per-cell basis, amazing! Only remaining challenge is totalling the operation for a range. Fumbling around with `SCAN` was fruitless, any suggestions for this final step?

Comment: @JakeLee answer updated

Answer (score 3):

Another idea is to substitute each `Example(\d+)` to `$1`  the [captured](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) [digit](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) and space `|.` [or](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) replace [anything else](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) with empty string ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/e8dJQ3/1)). Knowing that `$1` is unset on the right side of the alternation. Then split on space and sum up digits (any other occurring digits have been removed). If `Example` is a placeholder, replace with e.g. `[[:alpha:]]+` for one or more alphabetic characters.

```
=IF(ISTEXT(A1);SUM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1;"Example(\d+)|.";"$1 ");" "));0)
```

I added `IF(ISTEXT(A1);...)` for only processing text in the source field (to avoid errors). Else if empty or no text it's set to `0`. Just remove if  the field always contains text and this is unneeded.

[image]

Edit from @TheMaster: As a array formula, we can use `BYROW`

```
=BYROW(A:A; LAMBDA(row; IF(ISTEXT(row); SUM(SPLIT(
 REGEXREPLACE(row;"Example(\d+)|.";"$1 ");" "));)))
```